# Find a golden tile from a list of tiles

Tags: java

I had an interview and was asked a problem. I provided a solution and wanted to make sure if this is correct.

There is a `Tile` class. It has a boolean variable `isGoldenTile` which is `false` for all but `true` for one tile.

There is a `List<Tile> neighbors`. These are list of its immediate neighbors which are tiles.

There is a method `getNeighbors()` which returns the list of neighbors.

Finally, there is a method `findGoldenTile` which returns a `Tile` object. This returns the golden tile.

In no way I could alter the class except for the method body for `findGoldenTile`.

Here is my solution:

```
public class Tile {

    private boolean isGoldenTile = false;   
    private List<Tile> neighbors = null;

    public Tile(boolean isGoldenTile, List<Tile> neighbors) {
        this.isGoldenTile = isGoldenTile;
        this.neighbors = neighbors;
    }

    public boolean isGoldenTile() {
        return isGoldenTile;
    }

    public List<Tile> getNeighbors() {
        return neighbors;
    }

    public Tile findGoldenTile() {
        if(this.isGoldenTile == true){
            return this;
        } else if (this.getNeighbors().size() > 0){
            for(int i=0;i<this.getNeighbors().size();i++){
                if(this.getNeighbors().get(i).isGoldenTile == true){
                    return this.getNeighbors().get(i);
                }
            }
        } else {
            for(int i=0;i<this.getNeighbors().size();i++){
                return this.getNeighbors().get(i).findGoldenTile();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: btw. you don't need to compare a ``boolean`` with ``true``, just write ``if(condition)`` and accessing member fields/methods with using ``this`` is explicit, you can drop that unless there is a naming conflict with a local variable. So ``if(this.isGoldenTile == true)`` becomes ``if(isGoldenTile)``

Comment: Is there any guarantee that a neighbor of tile X contains X as a neighbor?

Comment: If you search recursively (as you do), you also need to keep track of visited tiles, or you risk ending in an infinite recursive loop, and for this you will need some data structure, like a set, with all the tiles already visited, as a parameter to `findGoldenTile`. Alternatively, you could not make it recursive, but with a queue and with the visited set in the method itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to keep track of visited tiles, or you risk ending in an infinite (recursive) loop. If you use recursion, and if you are not allowed to change the class, this is difficult, as you'd need to add another parameter to `findGoldenTile` holding the already visited tiles.

Alternatively, you could not make it recursive, but with a queue and with the set of visited tiles in the method itself. Something like this (not tested):

```
public Tile findGoldenTile() {
    Set<Tile> visited = new HashSet<>();
    LinkedList<Tile> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    queue.add(this);
    visited.add(this);
    while (! queue.isEmpty()) {
        Tile tile = queue.pop();
        if (tile.isGoldenTile) {
            return tile;
        }
        for (Tile x : tile.neighbors) {
            if (! visited.contains(x)) {
                queue.add(x);
                visited.add(x);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: queue and visited should be avalible for all Tiles. It should be static or you should put it as parameter. findGoldenTile(visited). Im not sure that you need a queue.

Comment: @CyberAleks It should be a parameter or static (ugh) when using recursion, but in the iterative approach, a local variable is fine.

Comment: I think @tobias_k's implementation is making sense. You cannot leave the context of the first method (so you can keep track of exploration state). So using a queue of work is really the only solution.

Comment: Ahh.. I understood. Sure, that makes sense. Sorry.

Comment: beautiful iterative solution, check mine for the recursive variant :)

Answer (score 1):

The method findGoldenTile cannot get the correct answers.

```
for (int i=0;i<this.getNeighbors().size();i++){
    return this.getNeighbors().get(i).findGoldenTile();
}
```

The above code will just return `this.getNeighbors().get(0).findGoldenTile()`
Because the return will exit from the function.
And also,

```
else if (this.getNeighbors().size() > 0) {
    ...   
} else {
    ...
}
```

You first judge the size of neigbors is greater than 0, then the else will execute when the size is 0, which means the neighbors is empty(). That will cause the error.

This is my code.

```
public Tile findGoldenTile() {
    if(this.isGoldenTile == true){
        return this;

    for(int i=0; i < this.neighbors.size();i++){
        Tile tile = this.neighbors.get(i).findGoldenTile();
        if (tile != null)
            return tile;    
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a verifiable solution to a recusive search algorithm:

**Model:**

[image: model]

**Code:**

```
public class Tile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // setup tiles
        Tile a = new Tile("a");
        Tile b = new Tile("b");
        Tile c = new Tile("c");
        Tile d = new Tile("d", true);
        Tile e = new Tile("e");
        Tile f = new Tile("f");

        // setup connections
        connect(a, b);
        connect(a, c);
        connect(b, d);
        connect(b, e);
        connect(d, f);
        connect(c, e);

        // test findGoldenTile method
        test(a);
        test(b);
        test(c);
        test(d);
        test(e);
        test(f);
    }

    public static void test(Tile tile) {
        System.out.println(tile + ".findGoldenTile()=" + tile.findGoldenTile());
    }

    public static void connect(Tile a, Tile b) {
        a.neighbors.add(b);
        b.neighbors.add(a);
    }

    private final String identity;
    private boolean isGoldenTile;
    private List<Tile> neighbors;

    public Tile(String identity) {
        this(identity, false);
    }

    public Tile(String identity, boolean isGoldenTile) {
        this(identity, isGoldenTile, new ArrayList<>());
    }

    public Tile(String identity, boolean isGoldenTile, List<Tile> neighbors) {
        this.identity = identity;
        this.isGoldenTile = isGoldenTile;
        this.neighbors = neighbors;
    }

    public String getIdentity() {
        return identity;
    }

    public boolean isGoldenTile() {
        return isGoldenTile;
    }

    public List<Tile> getNeighbors() {
        return neighbors;
    }

    public Tile findGoldenTile() {
        if (isGoldenTile) {
            return this;
        } else {
            // start recursion
            return findGoldenTile(new HashSet<>());
        }
    }

    protected Tile findGoldenTile(Set<Tile> visited) {
        visited.add(this);
        if(isGoldenTile) {
            return this;
        }
        for (Tile t : neighbors) {
            if(visited.contains(t)) {
                continue;
            }
            //recursive call
            Tile result = t.findGoldenTile(visited);
            if (result != null) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return identity;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
a.findGoldenTile()=d
b.findGoldenTile()=d
c.findGoldenTile()=d
d.findGoldenTile()=d
e.findGoldenTile()=d
f.findGoldenTile()=d
```

Comment: +1 for the testing harness, but given OP's requirement "In no way I could alter the class except for the method body for findGoldenTile." this would probably not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use .get() on list, because you do not know its implementation. If this would be a LinkedList, the complexity would grow drastically.

Also list can be null, you should check that before you call "size" on it.

```
List<Tile> actualNeighbors = this.getNeighbors();
//...
if (actualNeighbors != null && actualNeighbors.size > 0)
//...
for (Tile tile : actualNeighbors){
}
```

Also this does not make sense

```
} else {
            for(int i=0;i<this.getNeighbors().size();i++){
```

To this "else" part you get only if this is false `this.getNeighbors().size() > 0`, which means size of neighbours is 0

---

Also tip for solution - the biggest problem is, that you cant use recursion, because you cant track what you have visited and what you did not (as far as you cant add parameters to findGoldenTile method) - you can end in cycles.

You just have to keep the map of visited tiles in your method and go to "neighbours of neigbour" deeper and deeper and you have to check in your map, if you already visited it or not.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as there is no question.

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman - this is the question : `I had an interview and was asked a problem. I provided a solution and wanted to make sure if this is correct.` I am saying what probably the guy who would look at this solution would say.

Answer (score 0):

Your findGoldenTile() method is not correct i guess. Firt of all, I think, your "else" block at the end makes no sence. Your "else if" block is false. You should check findGoldenTile() there. And you make too much loops when you call .get(i) on a list each time. You should have somethink like this.

```
if(this.isGoldenTile == true){
     return this;
} 
for(Tile n : this.getNeighbors()){
     Tile golden = n.findGoldenTile();    
     if(golden != null){
        return golden;
     }
}
return null;
```